# How to control Windows 10 Mobile Hotpot settings from C# Windows application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10-desktop, hotspot

I'm developing a Windows application in C# and distribute it with a PC with Windows Home operating system to customers. I'd like to make the PC a wireless hotspot.

I tried creating a hosted network, but NETSH WLAN show drivers reports that the driver does not support hosted network. I can create a hotspot using Windows settings Mobile hotspot manually. Searching online I can only find code that runs on WinRT.

Is there a way to do what Windows Settings Mobile Hotspot control does in C#?
[image]

Comment: *"I can only find code that runs on WinRT"* - What's the specific issue with that? You're on Windows 10, so just go ahead and use what's available on Windows 10.

Comment: The issue was that I was hoping to get code examples for Winform application to extend the business' main program.

Comment: You have full access to the Windows Runtime from a Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to do what Windows Settings Mobile Hotspot control does in C#?

Currently, there is fewer documents on this. I checked [official code sample](https://github.com/Deeswoc/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HotspotAuthentication), it looks easy to understand. We use xml file to store hotspot configuration. And it contains `SSID` encryption protocol `HotspotProfile` etc. And then, we call [`ProvisionFromXmlDocumentAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.provisioningagent.provisionfromxmldocumentasync?view=winrt-22000) to load xml info and create hotspot. For more info please refer to this [case reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57706487/7254781).

Comment: Thanks you. I'll try that.